# using 'tezos-client import keys from mnemonic' differs from kukai (correct) fundraiser public key

Tags: tezos-client, delegation

i have tezos fundraiser tokens and also an exchange-sourced local node.

i have used kukai successfully to access the fundraiser account however when i am attempting delegation to the new account for baking (another tz1 running edo/latest) the mnemonic public key is not the same for kukai (the correct result) and the commandline

`tezos-client import keys from mnemonic`

the only switches are "encyrpt" and "force" for cmdline, niether seems to be what i need to follow kukai's differentiation of mnemonic imports and fundraiser imports.

is there a cmdline hack im not seeing in the online docks?

Comment: i found my answer with tezos-client man -v 0

Comment: So what is the answer? Maybe you could write a reply to your own question.